# how to use exe project as dll?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I created some project that contains a class ( using them as object instance ). 
This project was POC to check some possibility -

Now I want to convert this project to dll - and import this dll to some other exe project.

I change the configuration Type of the project to "Dynamic Library ( .dll)" - and compile its ok.

But how I import this dll to my new exe project and use those classes from the other exe ?

Do I need to add some "dllExport" definition in some place on the dll project?

Comment: Do you want to load the library at the beginning of your program or dynamically at some point later? If you want to load it at the beginning you simply need to link against that library/exe to use its content

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define a separate entry point for a DLL. An executable has the standard entry point:

```
int main(int argc, char* argue[], char* envy[]);
```

However for a Windows DLL, you need to define [dllmain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dllmain) which will be called when the module is loaded and unloaded:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved);
```

Further reading on [Dynamic Link Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-libraries).